# Using index on `LIKE :varname || '%'` in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-like

I have a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT FKDOCUMENT
FROM PNTM_DOCUMENTS_FT_INDEX
WHERE WORD LIKE 'sometext%'
```

> PLAN SORT ((PNTM_DOCUMENTS_FT_INDEX INDEX (IX_PNTM_DOCUMENTS_FT_INDEX)))

And it works okay.

Howver, when I try to use concatenated string with `LIKE`, Firebird does not use indices:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FKDOCUMENT
FROM PNTM_DOCUMENTS_FT_INDEX
WHERE WORD LIKE 'sometext' || '%'
```

> PLAN SORT ((PNTM_DOCUMENTS_FT_INDEX NATURAL))

How to force it to use indices?

Comment: If the wildcard is always in the end, then use `STARTING` instead of `LIKE`, ie `where word starting 'foo'` - thats should be more optimizer friendly.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the content of your question. Do you use a parameter as in the title, or plain string concatenation as in the second example (or do both have the same effect?)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Both have the same effect

Comment: For the case of a parameter it is entirely understandable (the optimizer needs to take into account that you might provide a value starting with `%` or `_`), but for a literal value it should be possible to optimize it to the equivalent of the first. You might want to consider filing an improvement ticket on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer, as ain already commented, is to use `STARTING [WITH]` instead of `LIKE` if you don't need a like pattern, but always want to do a prefix search. So:

```
WHERE WORD STARTING WITH 'sometext' -- No %!
```

or

```
WHERE WORD STARTING WITH :param
```

As far as I know this is exactly what Firebird does with `LIKE 'sometext%'`. This will use an index when available, and you don't need to escape it for presence of like pattern symbols. The downside is that you can't use like pattern symbols.

Now as to why Firebird doesn't use an index when you use

```
WHERE WORD LIKE :param || '%' -- (or LIKE :param) for that matter
```

or

```
WHERE WORD LIKE 'sometext' || '%'
```

The first case is easily explained: statement preparation is done separately from execution. Firebird needs to take into account the possibility that the parameter value starts with a `_` or - worse - a `%`, and it can't use an index for that.

As to the second case, it should be possible to optimize it to the equivalent of `LIKE 'sometext%'`, but Firebird probably considers anything that is not a plain literal as not optimizable. For this specific example it would be possible to decide it should be optimizable, but this a very specific exception (usually one doesn't concatenate literals like this, most of the time one or more 'black' boxes like columns, functions, case statements etc are involved).